# Why jquery append function does not works inside sendMessage function?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code. I need to run an append() jquery instruction inside sendMessage() function but it does not work as you can see from the code. It works perfectly outside the function, one row below (book.html.append("TEST)).

How can I solve? ([attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaE0t.png))

Comment: Please don't put code in an image. Instead paste the code as text in the question itself.

Comment: could be a scope issue - use `for(const book of books)` instead

Comment: @DomenicoTaffuri see duplicate link above as to why using `const` fixed it :)